# Finding the equations of the tangents to a circle with center $(3a,0)$

Tags: geometry

I have this question (which I've redacted):

> A point P moves in the x-y plane so that its distance from the origin, O, is twice its distance from the point with coordinates $(3a,0)$. If the tangents from O to the circle are OL and OM, find the equations of OL and OM.

I calculated the equation of the circle to be $(x-4a)^2+y^2=4a^2$ i.e. a center of $(4a,0)$ and a radius of $2a$. If the radius is the perpendicular line to both tangents, it becomes obvious that the *length* of both is:

$$
L = \sqrt{(4a)^2-(2a)^2} = 2\sqrt{3}a
$$

How do I get the equations of these two tangents? I tried using the discriminant (by subsituting $y^2=m^2x^2$), but that didn't work. The answer is $\sqrt3 y=\pm x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $C = (4a,0)$ be the center of the circle. Consider $\triangle OLC$; this is a right triangle. You want to determine $\angle LOC$. Since you know the side opposite $O$ (the radius of the circle) and the hypotenuse ($OC$), you can use some trigonometry to determine $\angle LOC$ and thus the slope of the tangent line.

Comment: Just because $L$ touches the circle doesn't mean that $\triangle OLC$ is a right-angled triangle does it? I didn't think that $L$ or $M$ sat above the centre... I know that $\angle LOC = 30$...

Comment: Yes, it does. Tangents are always perpendicular to the radius. Also, if you already know that $\angle LOC = 30$ degrees, then you are done! You can use that to compute the slope of the line.

Comment: Let the hypothenuse (also the radius) be $4a$, and the angle  30; then the adjacent (the length of the tangent) must equal  $a\sqrt3$ right?

Comment: Actually, the length of the adjacent is $2a\sqrt{3}$, but you don't need that. If you know the angle is $30^{\circ}$, then the slope of the line is just $\tan 30^{\circ}$.